# I thought I was accepting default options in apt dist-upgrade, but it's still hanging

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to install the `kali-linux-default` Kali metapackage onto a docker container without having to interact with it, but it's still prompting me to interact with it.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling

# Run basic commands to update the image
RUN apt update
RUN apt dist-upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"
RUN apt autoremove -y
RUN apt clean -y
RUN apt install kali-linux-default -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"
```

However, as you can see below, it's asking me to choose "yes" or "no"

```
...
Setting up libnpth0:amd64 (1.6-3) ...
Setting up hdparm (9.58+ds-5) ...
Setting up libprotobuf23:amd64 (3.12.3-2+b2) ...
Setting up krb5-locales (1.18.3-4) ...
Setting up kismet-capture-common (2020.12.R3-0kali1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring kismet-capture-common
---------------------------------

Kismet needs root privileges for some of its functions. However, running it as
root ("sudo kismet") is not recommended, since running all of the code with
elevated privileges increases the risk of bugs doing system-wide damage.
Instead Kismet can be installed with the "setuid" bit set, which will allow it
to grant these privileges automatically to the processes that need them,
excluding the user interface and packet decoding parts.

Enabling this feature allows users in the "kismet" group to run Kismet (and
capture packets, change wireless card state, etc), so only thoroughly trusted
users should be granted membership of the group.

For more detailed information, see the Kismet 010-suid.md, which can be found
at "/usr/share/doc/kismet-doc/readme/010-suid.md" in kismet-doc package or
"https://www.kismetwireless.net/docs/readme/suid/".

Install Kismet "setuid root"? [yes/no]
```

If I choose "yes", then I can hear my computer's fans spinning down and it just never proceeds. I assume this is because Kismet is trying to prompt the user to interact with the terminal GUI which I believe I've recalled several times.

Any suggestions on how to *truly* get to a non-interactive `apt install` process?

Answer (score 2):

Needed to add an extra "q" to the flags. For example:

`apt install -yqq`

as opposed to

`apt install -yq`

After adding the second "q", this fixed it for me.